# nextjs prodution build failed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

while running npm run build for the production build of the nextjs app
I am getting this error

Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

Automatically optimizing pages ..
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypted' of undefined

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypted' of undefined

Error occurred prerendering page "/404.html". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypted' of undefined

> Build error occurred
>   Error: Export encountered errors
>       at _default (/home/osis/raj_server/mobile-web/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:19:1164)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>       at async build (/home/osis/raj_server/mobile-web/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:36:218)
>   Automatically optimizing pages .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! mobile-web@0.1.0 build: `next build`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the mobile-web@0.1.0 build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/osis/.npm/_logs/2020-06-12T12_20_18_063Z-debug.log